# " RuntimeError: Model class wagtail.core.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS"

Tags: django, reactjs, wagtail

I followed Brent Clark on wagtail site. I was trying to add wagtail cms to react application using GraphQL and Python+Django on the back end. When I try to migrate i get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class wagtail.core.models.Site doesn't declare
an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

pip freeze gives:

```
aniso8601==3.0.2 
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3 
certifi==2018.8.13 
chardet==3.0.4 
Django==2.0.8 
django-modelcluster==4.2 
django-taggit==0.23.0 
django-treebeard==4.3 
django-webpack-loader==0.6.0 
djangorestframework==3.8.2 
draftjs-exporter==2.1.2 
graphene==2.1.3 
graphene-django==2.1.0 
graphql-core==2.1 
graphql-relay==0.4.5 
html5lib==1.0.1 
idna==2.7 
iso8601==0.1.12 
Pillow==5.2.0 
promise==2.1 
psycopg2==2.7.5 
pytz==2018.5 
requests==2.19.1 
Rx==1.6.1 
singledispatch==3.4.0.3 
six==1.11.0 
typing==3.6.4 
Unidecode==0.4.21 
urllib3==1.23 
wagtail==2.1.2 
webencodings==0.5.1 
Willow==1.1
```

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py`? What is your Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that you don't have the app installed in your settings.py file.

You need to add this to the setting "INSTALLED_APPS":

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
]
```

Also, you need to add the ID of the SITE you are configuring:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Comment: In this case, the item to add to INSTALLED_APPS would be `'wagtail.core'`, not `'django.contrib.sites'` - Wagtail has its own separate `Site` model.